# Error with layout on new application project

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I create a new application project on Eclipse, but it gives immediatly errors on the code of the MainActivity.class.
The error is on the R. of the setcontentview

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

But if I import android.R, then it gives error on the words activity_main (it doesn't recognize it like a layout), and on the word main.
What can I do? It's strange that the error is on applications just created.

Comment: can you show all the code in that file? I think it's because of your package.

Comment: I solved creating a new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Check your resources file. If you have errors `R.java` will not be generated. Fix the errors and clean and build.

Do not import `android.R`.

`android.R` refers to the resources under android framework. Instead you should refer to the resources under your package name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the layout `activity_main.xml` within `res/layout` directory and the menu `main.xml` within `res/menu` directory.

You shouldn't import `android.R`